# Contact Form 7 Selectable Pipe Recipients

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

I followed the rules they gave on their site.

```
[select* email-recipient “Sales|sales@yourdomain.com” “Tech Support|support@yourdomain.com” “Inquiry|info@yourdomain.com”]
```

And when I put `[email-recipient]` to Mail Tab it says: "Invalid mailbox syntax is used."

Can somebody please tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using wrong double quotes, I have corrected it here and checked in my contact form , it's working well.

```
[select* email-recipient "Sales|sales@yourdomain.com" "Tech Support|support@yourdomain.com" "Inquiry|info@yourdomain.com"]
```

Comment: I don't know what double quotes are you using, but you are savior! I even copied whole code from their official documentation and wanted to implement those. Still gave me the error. With your code it works. Magic!

Comment: Actually I found what it is. All the time I have used cyrillic character and it wouldn't let me proceed. Still very big thanks to You!

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is correct, but not having the form field required also produces this issue.